# Properties of richtextbox control cannot be set

Tags: vb6, richtextbox

On one computer `'A'` (win vista 32 bit) if I run my program in debug mode all the richtextbox controls throw `'property cannot be set'` errors.
I can go on to build the `exe` (without error ) and the full application OK
But when I then install and run the application on this computer or on computer `'B'` (win xp) the same problems occur on both.

However if I run the exact same code in debug mode on computer '`B`' there are no errors.
If I build and install the application on computer '`B`' it works fine. If I then install this application on computer '`A`' it also works fine.
When putting together the application for distribution, both computers use identical copies of `richtx32.ocx` (it, like the code, is checked out from the same repository).

If I check out previous copies of the code on computer'`A`' (that used to previously behave OK) they also now exhibit the same problems as the latest version of the code.

I don't have a clue what's going on, please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bad richtx32.oca file in the system32 directory seems to have been the cause of this.

[Here's](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149429) what an .oca file does:

> Some of the properties of the control are provided by the framework
>   and some by the control itself. Programmatically, the properties from
>   the framework and the control all appear as properties of the control.
>
> In order for these properties to appear, Visual Basic creates an
>   extended type library when the control is loaded into the toolbox.
>   Because the process of reading the control's type library and creating
>   the extended type library is time consuming, Visual Basic caches the
>   extended type library information into an OCA file.
>
> If you delete the OCA file for a control Visual Basic recognized,
>   Visual Basic will recreate the .OCA file when you load a project
>   requiring the control. This recreation process comes with a time
>   penalty.

So it seems that having a bad .oca file in existence can mean that the properties of the control both in the IDE and in the compiled .exe will be affected.
The solution is to delete the .oca file in the system32 folder and then load the project again.

Comment: @Lynn Crumbling, Thanks, I thought it was the ocx but thanks to your input we'd pretty much eliminated that so it was just tinkering around that made me look at the oca. Course I've no idea HOW that got corrupted :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing multiple references to the `Property cannot be set` message being resolved in the version of the Rich Text Control that is [distributed in Visual Studio 6.0 Service Pack 4](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/212733), and another `Property cannot be set` [message fixed in SP5](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/199722).

First and foremost, make sure that a minimum of SP5 is installed; I'd just go with SP6.

For reference, my Microsoft Rich Textbox Control 6.0 (SP6) is at `C:\Windows\System32\RICHTX32.OCX`, and is version **6.1.97.82**.

I know you said that both machines have the same copy of the control installed; for the sake of completeness, you may want to double-check that the new control was registered after installation.

**EDIT:**

I exported the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3B7C8860-D78F-101B-B9B5-04021C009402}` reg key:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3B7C8860-D78F-101B-B9B5-04021C009402}]
@="Microsoft Rich Textbox Control 6.0 (SP6)"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3B7C8860-D78F-101B-B9B5-04021C009402}\Control]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3B7C8860-D78F-101B-B9B5-04021C009402}\Implemented Categories]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3B7C8860-D78F-101B-B9B5-04021C009402}\Implemented Categories\{0DE86A52-2BAA-11CF-A229-00AA003D7352}]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3B7C8860-D78F-101B-B9B5-04021C009402}\Implemented Categories\{0DE86A53-2BAA-11CF-A229-00AA003D7352}]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3B7C8860-D78F-101B-B9B5-04021C009402}\Implemented Categories\{0DE86A57-2BAA-11CF-A229-00AA003D7352}]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3B7C8860-D78F-101B-B9B5-04021C009402}\Implemented Categories\{40FC6ED4-2438-11CF-A3DB-080036F12502}]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3B7C8860-D78F-101B-B9B5-04021C009402}\Implemented Categories\{40FC6ED5-2438-11CF-A3DB-080036F12502}]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3B7C8860-D78F-101B-B9B5-04021C009402}\Implemented Categories\{7DD95802-9882-11CF-9FA9-00AA006C42C4}]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3B7C8860-D78F-101B-B9B5-04021C009402}\InprocServer32]
@="C:\\Windows\\system32\\RICHTX32.OCX"
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3B7C8860-D78F-101B-B9B5-04021C009402}\MiscStatus]
@="0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3B7C8860-D78F-101B-B9B5-04021C009402}\MiscStatus\1]
@="131473"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3B7C8860-D78F-101B-B9B5-04021C009402}\ProgID]
@="RICHTEXT.RichtextCtrl.1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3B7C8860-D78F-101B-B9B5-04021C009402}\Programmable]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3B7C8860-D78F-101B-B9B5-04021C009402}\ToolboxBitmap32]
@="C:\\Windows\\system32\\RICHTX32.OCX, 1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3B7C8860-D78F-101B-B9B5-04021C009402}\TypeLib]
@="{3B7C8863-D78F-101B-B9B5-04021C009402}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3B7C8860-D78F-101B-B9B5-04021C009402}\Version]
@="1.2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3B7C8860-D78F-101B-B9B5-04021C009402}\VersionIndependentProgID]
@="RICHTEXT.RichtextCtrl"
```

Comment: Hi Lynn I'm also running vb6 SP6 on both machines and the version of richtx32.ocx in my system32 folders is the same as yours. To make things as minimal as possible I also created a very simple project with  1 control a richtextbox control and just 1 line of code. This line of code is in the form_load event and is richtextbox1.text = "!". If I run this in the IDE in the xp machine it works and the exe i make there works on both machines. If I run it in the IDE on the vista there's the "property cannot be set" error and the exe I make there has this runtime error on both machines. Bizarre

Comment: Can you confirm that `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3B7C8860-D78F-101B-B9B5-04021C009402}\InprocServer32` points to the 6.1.97.82 version of the control?

Comment: I have 3 entries there, the RICHTX32.OCX referred to is the  6.1.97.82 one, I've no idea what the other 2 entries are about

Name:   (Default)     
Type : REG_SZ  
data: C:\Windows\system32\RICHTX32.OCX      


Name:   InprocServer32  
Type:   REG_MULTI_SZ   
data :   4)tks6m$?YYV+r,8PxQReaders>wm,0bulsi=dmPn!6{HhL


Name: ThreadingModel  
Type:  REG_SZ      
data:  Apartment

Comment: I edited my post to include my dumped reg key for you can compare against. Also, it might be worth your time to unregister the OCX and re-register it.

Comment: Thanks Lynn, I registered and unregistered it but the problem remained the same. Since I'd seen a mention of richtx32.oca when I looked at the code of the compiled (very simple program) I wondered if it was something to do with that. I read a mention here ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149429 ) that vb needs these .oca files but that if you delete them they will be recreated. Rather than delete it,  I renamed the file. I then loaded the project again and it ran OK. So it seems to have been a bad .oca file. Thanks very much it was great to get to the bottom of it!

Comment: If you'd like a bad richtx32.oca I'll send you a copy!

Comment: Ha. That's awesome that you figured it out. I never would have suspected the .oca file.